VKTM detected a forward time drift in oracle database 19c
I'm running an Oracle 19c Standard Edition 2 database (version 19.16.0.0.0) on a Linux server, and I've been seeing repeated warnings related to time drift detected by the VKTM process. Below are some of the log entries I've encountered:

2024-08-03T13:17:07.281085+02:00
Warning: VKTM detected a forward time drift.
Please see the VKTM trace file for more details:
/oracle/diag/rdbms/impdbp/impdbp/trace/impdbp_vktm_863407.trc


2024-09-14T11:05:19.395852+02:00
Warning: VKTM detected a forward time drift.
Please see the VKTM trace file for more details:

I've checked the trace file, and it shows several entries like this:

kstmchkdrift (kstmhighrestimecntkeeper:highres): Time jumped forward
by (2307054) usec whereas (1000000) is allowed

The server is a virtual machine running on Oracle Linux with chronyd for time synchronization. I have verified that chronyd is active, and the system is synchronized with NTP servers. Despite this, I keep encountering these time drift warnings.
full:
Trace file /oracle/diag/rdbms/impdbp/impdbp/trace/impdbp_vktm_863407.trc
Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.16.0.0.0
Build label:    RDBMS_19.16.0.0.0DBRU_LINUX.X64_220701
ORACLE_HOME:    /oracle/impuls/19c/db_home1
System name:    Linux
Node name:      amvmor1.andoria.net
Release:        5.4.17-2136.319.1.2.el8uek.x86_64
Version:        #2 SMP Wed May 10 16:51:29 PDT 2023
Machine:        x86_64
Instance name: impdbp
Redo thread mounted by this instance: 0 <none>
Oracle process number: 5
Unix process pid: 863407, image: oracle@amvmor1.andoria.net (VKTM)


*** 2024-09-14T11:05:19.218459+02:00 (CDB$ROOT(1))
*** SESSION ID:(956.5970) 2024-09-14T11:05:19.237134+02:00
*** CLIENT ID:() 2024-09-14T11:05:19.253894+02:00
*** SERVICE NAME:() 2024-09-14T11:05:19.253909+02:00
*** MODULE NAME:() 2024-09-14T11:05:19.253925+02:00
*** ACTION NAME:() 2024-09-14T11:05:19.253933+02:00
*** CLIENT DRIVER:() 2024-09-14T11:05:19.253940+02:00
*** CONTAINER ID:(1) 2024-09-14T11:05:19.253949+02:00


*** TRACE FILE RECREATED AFTER BEING REMOVED ***

kstmchkdrift (kstmhighrestimecntkeeper:highres): Time jumped forward by (2429544)usec at (9465508362913) whereas (1000000) is allowed

*** 2024-09-14T11:05:19.475008+02:00 (CDB$ROOT(1))
kstmchkdrift (kstmhighrestimecntkeeper:lowres): Time stalled at 1726304719

*** 2024-09-14T11:05:20.505713+02:00 (CDB$ROOT(1))
kstmchkdrift (kstmhighrestimecntkeeper:lowres): Stall, backward drift ended at 1726304720 drift: 1

[.....@amvmor2 ~]# chronyc sources
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
^~ 185.231.150.1                 2   6   377    39   -580ms[ -580ms] +/-   62ms
^~ 212.127.78.21                 2   6   377    42   -407ms[ -38.3s] +/- 7556us
^~ ip-89-161-47-136.tel.tkb>     2   6   377    39   -587ms[ -587ms] +/-   29ms
^* ntp3.orange.pl                1   6   377    41   -573ms[ -38.4s] +/-   19ms

My questions are:

What might be causing these time drifts detected by VKTM, especially
considering that NTP synchronization seems to be working correctly?
Are there specific Oracle configuration or OS-level settings I
should    check to minimize these time drifts? Could this be related
to the       virtualized environment, and if so, what are best
practices for time     synchronization in Oracle databases running
on VMs? Any insights or      recommendations would be greatly
appreciated!

Thanks in advance for your help.

[root@amvmor2 ~]# chronyc tracking
Reference ID    : BCF11CFE (0.ntp.epix.net.pl)
Stratum         : 2
Ref time (UTC)  : Sat Oct 19 15:23:23 2024
System time     : 2.129428387 seconds slow of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.204730481 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.204730481 seconds
Frequency       : 222333.641 ppm slow
Residual freq   : +178407.516 ppm
Skew            : 129.940 ppm
Root delay      : 0.005807488 seconds
Root dispersion : 4.113684177 seconds
Update interval : 1.0 seconds
Leap status     : Normal

